# facebook Like and comment not working in ios

Tags: ios, ios7, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I am working on Facebook like and comment in ios,i am getting the response i.e id of a like object.But it is not showing in Facebook.I am using this code to like a object.

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                           @"http://samples.ogp.me/226075010839791", @"object",
                           nil
                       ];
```

/* make the API call */

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/og.likes"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                          id result,
                          NSError *error
                      ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                      }];
```

I am getting one more problem i.e if i clicked on another object of a same user it is giving an error.
 **message = "(#3501) User is already associated to the object type, website, on a unique action type Like. Original Action ID: 654561277932515";**

Please help me.

Comment: I have the same problem bro. It worked before but not anymore